# Change value of widget inside GWT flex table when other widget's value changes?

Tags: gwt

Ok, so I have a pretty specific and to me quite complicated issue, as I'm a GWT newbie.

I have a GWT flex table, which I use to dynamically add rows, whose cells contain GWT widgets. The row number changes, but the number of columns in static, always 6. Each row contains a cell with a remove button and five cells each with their own textbox.

What I need to do is somehow code a kind of relationship between the textbox in cell 6 of one row and the textbox in cell 5 in the next row (and vice versa).

To illustrate: when something changes in the textbox at [1,6] the content of textbox at [2,5] needs to be overwritten with the same value. If the textbox at [2,5] changes the textbox at [1,6] needs to change as well. I cannot use a button to commit the changes, it needs to happen via onValueChange or Blur or something similar, which doesn't require the user to perform a specific action.

My problem stems mostly from trying to figure out how to address specific cells in the flex table and their content. For the remove button the solution was easy enough with a click event handler, but for this issue I just can't seem to be able to come up with a solution.

Sadly I also cannot provide any of the code which I have up until now, since it's a business secret. I can only give a broad description of the problem like the one above.

EDIT:
Actually, it's probably more a problem of not having much code in terms of this specific problem.

What I have is a flex table, which has initially only the header row. Upon clicking a button below this table the addNewField() method is called, which just contains the creation, setting of default values and adding of the text fields into a new row.

```
addNewField() {
int rows = flextable.getRowCount();
Button removeBtn = new Button("x");
removeBtn.getElement().setId(Integer.toString(rows));
//then the button's event handler
TextBox name = new TextBox();
name.setText("something");
flextable.setWidget(rows, 0, "name");
//repeat 4 more times with incrementing columns for the other widgets
}
```

This way I add entire rows of editable TextBoxes. What I need is a way to influence the values of the 6th column TextBox of a chosen row and the 5th column TextBox of chosen row + 1.

EDIT2: I've tried the dirty option just to see how it would go and somehow the compare inside the if breaks the app. The compiler detects a nullpointerexception and I can't even debug it with breakpoints because it fails to compile and won't start. I can't figure out why though. I threw the code directly into the event for testing purposes, so pardon the ugliness.

```
TextBox bis = new TextBox();
bis.setText(rows + ":10:00");
subs.setWidget(rows, 5, bis);

bis.addValueChangeHandler(new ValueChangeHandler<String>()
{

    @Override
    public void onValueChange(ValueChangeEvent<String> event)
    {
        allRows: for (int i = 0; i < subs.getRowCount(); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < subs.getCellCount(i); j++)
            {
                if ( subs.getWidget(i, j) == bis )
                {
                    TextBox widgetAtColumnSix = ((TextBox) subs.getWidget(i, 5));
                    String text = widgetAtColumnSix.getText();

                    TextBox widgetAtColumnFiveRowPlusOne = ((TextBox) subs.getWidget(i + 1, 4));
                    widgetAtColumnFiveRowPlusOne.setText(text);
                    break allRows;
                }

            }
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: Actually you can give a code example that works without giving away business secrets. Showing what you have done would help greatly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Since you edited your question and you dont want to use EventBus you could iterate over your `FlexTable` and set your `TextBox` value depending on your current rowIndex and cellIndex... Its not nice but it should work:

```
public class CellWidget extends Composite {

    private TextBox nameBox;

    public CellWidget() {
        FlowPanel flowPanel = new FlowPanel();
        Button deleteButton = new Button("x");
        nameBox = new TextBox();
        nameBox.addValueChangeHandler(new ValueChangeHandler<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onValueChange(ValueChangeEvent<String> event) {
                notifiyTextBox(CellWidget.this, event.getValue());
            }
        });
        flowPanel.add(nameBox);
        flowPanel.add(deleteButton);
        initWidget(flowPanel);
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        nameBox.setText(text);
    }

}

public void notifiyTextBox(CellWidget source, String string) {
    rows: for (int i = 0; i < flextable.getRowCount(); i++) {
        columns: for (int j = 0; j < flextable.getCellCount(i); j++) {
            if (flextable.getWidget(i, j) == source) {
                CellWidget widgetAtColumnSix = ((CellWidget) flextable.getWidget(i, 5));
                widgetAtColumnSix.setText(string);

                CellWidget widgetAtColumnFiveRowPlusOne = ((CellWidget) flextable.getWidget(i + 1, 4));
                widgetAtColumnFiveRowPlusOne.setText(string);
                break rows;
            }

        }
    }

}
```

I still would recommend using an eventbus. To make it even more convenient there is the [GWT Event Binder](https://github.com/google/gwteventbinder) lib, which makes using events a breeze.

So when you change a value in your textbox[2,5] it also fires your `CustomEvent`. All Widgets, that need to change their textbox value just need to catch...

Comment: Bear with me, it's literally my first time trying to make and understand an event listener that is not already built-in. I think I understand the basic structure of the custom event and the widget, but what I can't seem to grasp is how the event would know that it should change only one specific textBox and not all of them. How the event that happens at textBox [1,6] would know to affect only textBox [2,5], how textBox [2,6] would know only to affect textBox [3,6] etc.
Also I'm not sure if I'll even be able to use a custom library, if I won't is there another solution?

Comment: The EventBinder basically is just a wrapper for the build-in EventBus to reduce boilerplate(http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/event/shared/EventBus.html). The easiest way to differentiate to which event a TextBox should listen is to create different Events for each one. For example: `TextBox1ChangedEvent` and `TextBox2ChangedEvent`. If value of `TextBox1` changes it fires the `TextBox1ChangedEvent`. All other TextBoxes that you want to listen that will implement `void onEvent(TextBox1ChangedEvent event) ` and react on to it

Comment: I added a hopefully easier quick and dirty solution

Comment: I'll use the Event Binder if they'll let me but at least I also have an alternative if not. Thank you!

Comment: Actually I didnt test the dirty code, was just to give you a hint.. If any cell value could be null you should a if clause for that. also what happens if you edit the textbox in the last row? it will try to go to the next row and throw an exception.

Comment: I slept on this issue over the weekend and found out what the issue was (I forgot to make a variable I was calling final). So your dirty code actually works like a charm. Thanks again!

Comment: haha nice to hear that. anway keep in mind that using the EventBinder is recommended. if this solves your problem it would be nice if you'd accept this answer.